# Injecting Python Inside Include Tag in Django

Tags: python, html, django, web

I have urls saved in a db and I want to inject the urls into an include tag. What is the work around for this?

```
{% include {{ graphs.file.url }} %}
```

Comment: `include` would not work with a url, but you can pass it a template name. `{% include some_variable_with_a_template_name %}` Note the `{{` and `}}` are not required and would not work inside a template tag.

Comment: Yeah. An example of what it is in those injection tags {{}} would be "dynamic_media\test1.html". I routed my model files to go inside a template directory, because it is html. The variable is such that a user selects which template they want to display. So I couldn't just hard code a template name.

Comment: `{% include graphs.file.url %}`, but that will not work if this contains a *URL*, this should contain a path to a template you are rendering.

Comment: That will read as {% include \dynamic_media\test1.html %} not {% include "dynamic_media\test1.html" %}. There is two problems..."" not added and an extra \. Hard coding I can get around the extra \ by doing     {% include '..\templates\dynamic_media\test1.html' %}. How to do that while calling from a context_dict beats me.